# bamboo agent and docker connectivity, need explanation

Tags: docker, bamboo

we are using docker containers as Bamboo build agents.
we cannot ping directly from bamboo server to docker agents. but the other way is possible.

in this case, how bamboo server is able to start builds on the docker agents as soon as the plan started?

Comment: Has this been resolved?  Just starting to figure out how to run containerized remote agents and came across this post.

Comment: sorry, i don't remember what has happened, but it is something to do with docker entrypoint and bamboo internally does things.. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/running-a-docker-container-in-bamboo-962976995.html