# Docker Bamboo Agent not picking by Bamboo Plan

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, bamboo, agent

1. I have created the Docker image with Bamboo Agent installed.
2. Whenever I start Bamboo Agent - Docker container - the agent getting registered with Bamboo successfully.
3. After authentication I can see my Docker Bamboo agent listed under Online remote agents.
4. All agents capabilities are fine.
5. In Bamboo agent container log I can see - Bamboo agent 'Node 1' ready to receive builds.
6. Docker Agent is listing in Task capability as well.
7. Bamboo and the machine where the Docker is running - both in same network.
8. Docker using "host" network.
9. After I have started job I can see only below log in agent - but after Job got queued it not picking by Docker Bmaboo Agent:

`bamboo-agent_1           | INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/04/25 06:40:59 | 2020-04-25 06:40:58,927 INFO [remoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListenerContainer-1] [RemoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListener] ExecutableQueueUpdate: addToQueue, agents known to be affected: []
    bamboo-agent_1           | INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/04/25 06:40:59 | 2020-04-25 06:40:58,929 INFO [0-BAM::Node 1::Agent:pool-3-thread-1] [BuildAgentControllerImpl] Agent 294944816 checking build queue for executables...
    bamboo-agent_1           | INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/04/25 06:42:35 | 2020-04-25 06:42:35,317 INFO [remoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListenerContainer-1] [RemoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListener] ExecutableQueueUpdate: addToQueue, agents known to be affected: []
    bamboo-agent_1           | INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/04/25 06:42:35 | 2020-04-25 06:42:35,317 INFO [0-BAM::Node 1::Agent:pool-3-thread-1] [BuildAgentControllerImpl] Agent 294944816 checking build queue for executables...
    bamboo-agent_1           | INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/04/25 06:46:52 | 2020-04-25 06:46:52,152 INFO [remoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListenerContainer-1] [RemoteEventRebroadcasterMessageListener] ExecutableQueueUpdate: addToQueue, agents known to be affected: []`

Relatively same issue I believe but no answer : [bamboo agent and docker connectivity, need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508553/bamboo-agent-and-docker-connectivity-need-explanation)